# Как вывести нестандартные результаты в django?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django, orm

Есть три модели:

```
# Модель мероприятия
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Название мероприятия", max_length=25)
    location = models.CharField("Место проведения", max_length=25)

# Модель простого поста в блоге
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Заголовок поста", max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField("Текст поста", blank=True, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Дата публикации", default=timezone.now)

# Модель поста привязанного к конкретному мероприятию
class EventPost(Post):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Суть в том что нужно в блоге выводить все посты (связанные с меропр. и простые) по дате добавления, но к постам от мероприятий в шаблоне добавляется плашка с названием мероприятия и места. Т.е. можно объединить два запроса и передать в шаблон, но не могу придумать как вытащить в плашку значения из модели мероприятий.
Приходил в голову вариант сделать в модели EventPost свойство чтото типа

```
@property
def location(self):
    location = Event.objects.get(pk=self.event)
```

Но мне кажется это не очень правильный вариант (да и не факт что рабочий))

Comment: Зачем существует модель `EventPost`?  Почему бы не поместить `event = models.ForeignKey` прямо в модель `Post`?

Comment: Согласен, исправим. Меня больше интересует вопрос как в шаблоне обратиться к полю location связанного с постом мероприятия?

Comment: Если вы перенесёте `event` в модель `Post`, то самым обыкновенным `{{ пост.event.location }}`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь